# Create differenet keypath for different indexes in dexie.js?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

My indexeddb code is something like this.

```
let request = indexedDB.open("myDB", "1.0");

request.onupgradeneeded = e => { 
    var mystore = db.createObjectStore('detailsTable', {
                keyPath: 'detail_id'
            });
            mystore.createIndex('status', 'survey_status', {
                unique: false
            });
            mystore.createIndex('uwid', 'user_wave_id', {
                unique: true
            });
            mystore.createIndex('dirty_bit', 'dirty_bit', {
                unique: false
            });
};
```

So, my `status` has keypath as `survey_status`, `uwid` as `user_wave_id` same goes for `dirty_bit` also. I just try to create this in dexie.

```
const db = new Dexie("myDB");

db.version(1).stores({
  detailsTable:'&detail_id','status','uwid','dirty_bit'
});
```

But I don't know how to change the keypath of those indexes. Anyone, please help me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Dexie only cares about the keypaths. If you've created your DB outside Dexie and want to go over to using Dexie, it will adapt to using the exising indexes you've created no matter what names you've given them. Just specify the keypaths and Dexie will find the indexes.

Based on how you created your db and indexes, the corresponding dexie code would be:

```js
const db = new Dexie("myDB");

db.version(0.1).stores({
  detailsTable: "detail_id, survey_status, user_wave_id, dirty_bit"
});
```

The reason for using version(0.1) instead of just version(1) is described here: https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Migrating-existing-DB-to-Dexie

Comment: So, I can't able to use different index and keypath? like `status` is index `survey_status`. @David Fahlander

Comment: No Dexie has no API to specify the names of the indexes. The reason for this is based on the following citation from Phil Karlton: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things".

What would your specific use case for this be?